# Printing out relative date from current time

Tags: performance, c, datetime

Here is some code of mine that prints out the relative date according to the current time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 1;
  struct tm date = {0};
  char relativeDays[80];

  char* temp = strtok(argv[1], "/");
  while(temp != 0)
  {
    switch(i++)
    {
                case 1:
                        date.tm_mon  = atoi(temp) - 1;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        date.tm_mday = atoi(temp);
                        break;
                case 3:
                        date.tm_year = atoi(temp) - 1900;
    }
    temp=strtok(NULL, "/");
  }
  i = (int) difftime(time(NULL), mktime(&date))/86400;
  sprintf(relativeDays, "%d", abs(i));
  if (i > 0) printf("%s\n", strcat(relativeDays, " days ago."));
  else if (i < 0) printf("%s\n", strcat(relativeDays, " days from now."));
  else printf("Today\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

Sample input and output:

> ```
> $ ./date 12/8/2013
> 2 days ago.
> $ ./date 12/10/2013
> Today
> $ ./date 12/24/2013
> 13 days from now.
> ```

Any thoughts on how to improve the code, specifically how to make it shorter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Date-time handling is tricky to implement correctly.  Unless you want to reinvent the wheel, use `strptime(3)` to parse dates.  Your code will be simpler, and you should automatically get validation to reject dates like "12/32/2013".

When converting the input date to a Unix epoch value using `mktime(&date)`, you always interpret the date as midnight in the UTC time zone.  That leads to two bugs in calculating the date difference, in my opinion:

1. The user would expect the input date to be interpreted in the local time zone.
2. When specifying tomorrow's date (and interpreting it in the local time zone), the output will be `"Today"`, since 00:00:00 of the following day is less than 86400 seconds in the future.

The output routines could also use some slight improvement.  You need neither `abs()` nor `strcat()`.  Also, it would be human-friendly to handle singular numbers.

The magic number 86400 should be explained better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SECONDS_PER_DAY (24 * 60 * 60L)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *input_str;
    time_t now;
    struct tm input_tm = { 0 };
    long diff_days;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Need MM/DD/YYYY input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    input_str = argv[1];

    /* When calling difftime(), both arguments should have the same
       hr:min:sec, else you might get off-by-one-day errors depending on
       the time of day when you run the program.  We could either use
       00:00:00 midnight for both, or the current hr:min:sec for both.
       Let's use the current time for both. */
    time(&now);
    localtime_r(&now, &input_tm);

    /* strptime() will fill in MM/DD/YYYY, but leave the hr:min:sec and
       time zone fields from above alone. */
    if (!strptime(input_str, "%m/%d/%Y", &input_tm)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad date: %s\n", input_str);
        return 1;
    }
    diff_days = (long)difftime(now, mktime(&input_tm)) / SECONDS_PER_DAY;

    if (diff_days > 0) {
        printf("%ld day%s ago.\n", diff_days, (diff_days > 1 ? "s" : ""));
    } else if (diff_days < 0) {
        printf("%ld day%s from now.\n", -diff_days, (diff_days < -1 ? "s" : ""));
    } else {
        printf("Today\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: With 16-bit `int`, `86400` is recognized as needing a larger type, such as `long`.  Thus the division occurs with `(long) 86400`.  With the more understandably `(24 * 60 * 60)`, would such a compilation also come up with the same product or `(int) (24 * 60 * 60)` which is 20864?

Comment: @chux Good observation. I've widened the data types accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

I've commented your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    struct tm date = {0};
    char relativeDays[80];
```

Check For Proper Input

```
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Two arguments required!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char *temp = strtok(argv[1], "/");
```

`temp` will be `NULL` if empty.  Also, add a `break` after `case 3:` for consistency.  If you think you'll need to handle unexpected cases, use `default` at the end.

```
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        switch(i++)
        {
            case 1:
                date.tm_mon  = atoi(temp) - 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                date.tm_mday = atoi(temp);
                break;
            case 3:
                date.tm_year = atoi(temp) - 1900;
                break;
            default:
        }
```

Be consistent with spacing.

```
        temp = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }
```

Add comments so people know what your intentions are.  Why are you dividing by 86400?

```
    i = (int)difftime(time(NULL), mktime(&date)) / 86400;
    sprintf(relativeDays, "%d", abs(i));
```

Use spaces to make everything more readable.

```
    if(i > 0)
        printf("%s\n", strcat(relativeDays, " days ago."));
    else if(i < 0)
        printf("%s\n", strcat(relativeDays, " days from now."));
    else
        printf("Today\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

This while block can be changed to the following. Though it doesn't change the operation, it may improve the aesthetics.

```
while(temp != NULL)
{
    int num = atoi(temp);    
    switch(i++)
    {
        case 1:
            date.tm_mon = num - 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            date.tm_mday = num;
            break;
        case 3:
            date.tm_year = num - 1900;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unexpected input. Blowing up now!\n");
            break;
    }

    temp = strtok(NULL, "/");
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is `#define`d as `0`, so that shouldn't be the case. Perhaps a bug has been exposed.

Comment: You are right, it works.  I thought putting it in as `!temp` would give the same result, but it didn't.  Good advice overall (+1), but I was really looking for a way to shorten the code.

Comment: Hi, I've upvoted your answer - however be careful with comment-in-code answers, they might eventually get flagged as *code-only* posts - which are frowned upon. Take the time to format your answer, make it look good, lay down your thoughts in plain text - and of course include improved code blocks if you want to :)

Comment: Probably can't be shortened and still be readable.  Short code doesn't necessarily mean good code.

Comment: @retailcoder Thanks.  I didn't know that.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I agree, but if you look in the `while` loop I have, I convert a `char*` to an `int` every iteration of the loop instead of once outside of the loop. That could be a way to shorten it (I've tried to shorten it that way, but failed).

Comment: @syb0rg You can add `int num = atoi(temp);` right at the start of the `while` loop, before the `switch` and replace all the `atoi(temp)`s in your code with `num`.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey It broke the code :(

Comment: @syb0rg Can you tell me what input you're giving your program?  What is the string in `argv[1]`?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey I edited in some working I/O into my answer.  With your most recent edit, here is the I/O: `./clean 12/8/2013
16050 days ago.`

Comment: @syb0rg It's working for me.  Add `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` at the beginning of `main` and tell me what it says.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey `12/8/2013`

Comment: @syb0rg It's working for me.  Wish I could help you more.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: anyone working on this code will probably know, or easily deduce, that 86400 is the number of seconds in a day (60x60x24).  Not sure it needs a comment. Making it a named constant on the other hand...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey "NULL is #defined as 0" is incorrect for the language posted here (C).  You may find it true in other languages such as C++.

Answer (score 4):

Concerns if `argv[1]` represents a *local* time

1. Should add `date.tm_isdst = -1;`.  Although the h:m:s are set to 0, can't think of a dst change that crossed a day, so this is pedantic.

Other concerns.

1. Should check range of year, easy for folks to enter only last 2 digits and expect 13 to be 2013.

Comment: @syb0rg Alos: In effect, you are comparing the days elapsed since zero-hour of the supplied date (the first moment of that day) to "now".  Then  using `(int) difftime()`, you are rounding toward 0 that result.  The asymmetry of using "first moment" and "round toward 0" may be of concern.